# Gitlab CI/CD and Nx affected:build

Tags: gitlab, nrwl-nx

I'm having trouble getting Nx to build properly inside Gitlab's CI/CD tool.

```
> nx affected:build "--prod" "--base=remotes/origin/development~1" "--head=remotes/origin/development"
```

> fatal: Not a valid object name remotes/origin/development~1 Command
>   failed: git merge-base remotes/origin/development~1
>   remotes/origin/development fatal: Not a valid object name
>   remotes/origin/development~1

I've tried different branches/commands such as just a plain: `nx affected:build` and I get the same error(just with a master branch indicated in the error message)

Anyone able to get the Nx monorepo working with Gitlab?

Comment: I had similar issue in Jenkins. Firstly check if branch name is provided correctly. If development branch exists in origin then try to use it without remotes prefix: origin/development~1. Second issue was caused by plugin which is doing checkout, it was needed to disable shallow clone and enable fetching tags

Comment: I had the same issue on Gitlab CI. I have just pushed the `.gitlab-ci.yml` with `--base=remotes/origin/master` and same issue

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem. Running "git fetch" before the nx command fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It no longer works after the newest update. If you have a main branch name other than master and want to utilize the '--all' option, there is a correct way to specify command-line arguments.

**Try this**

> nx affected:build --all -- trunk HEAD

Notice the space after '--' before the branch name.